# Syntax error in query expression using sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT
(
SELECT Sum(tbl_allTransactions.transAmount) AS SumOftransAmount
FROM tbl_allTransactions
WHERE (((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Expense')) OR (((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Budget') AND ((tbl_allTransactions.[transMonth])=[@transMonth]))
GROUP BY tbl_allTransactions.transMonth
,

SELECT Sum(tbl_allTransactions.transAmount) AS SumOftransAmount
FROM tbl_allTransactions
WHERE (((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Expense')) OR (((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Budget') AND ((tbl_allTransactions.[transMonth])=[@transMonth]))
GROUP BY tbl_allTransactions.transMonth
)

FROM tbl_allTransactions WHERE (((tbl_allTransactions.[userID])=[@userID]))
```

I am getting following error:-

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14) Syntax error in query
expression '(SELECT Sum(tbl_allTransactions.transAmount) AS
SumOftransAmount FROM tbl_allTransactions WHERE
(((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Expense')) OR
(((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Budget') AND
((tbl_allTransactions.[transMonth])=[@transMonth])) GROUP '. at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResulthr) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
dbParams, Object& executeResult) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Obje
```

Comment: When I am running  single sub query it's working but when I am implementing two sub queries like above its giving error.

Comment: Can you please share the error's text?

Comment: How am I to share the snapshot of the error?

Comment: Copy and paste error message to your post. @AishwarCNigam

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14) Syntax error in query expression '(SELECT Sum(tbl_allTransactions.transAmount) AS SumOftransAmount FROM tbl_allTransactions WHERE (((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Expense')) OR (((tbl_allTransactions.[transType])='Budget') AND ((tbl_allTransactions.[transMonth])=[@transMonth])) GROUP '.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Obje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code was missing a closing parenthesis on the first subquery. The code was also simplified by consolidating the transType conditional from 2 statements to 1. Extra brackets were removed to enhance readability.  Also column aliases were added to output of each subquery. Since both queries render the same data, the second column was called "SumOftransAmount2"

```
SELECT
(SELECT Sum(tbl_allTransactions.transAmount)
FROM tbl_allTransactions
WHERE tbl_allTransactions.transType in ('Expense', 'Budget') AND tbl_allTransactions.transMonth = @transMonth
GROUP BY tbl_allTransactions.transMonth) as SumOftransAmount
,
(SELECT Sum(tbl_allTransactions.transAmount)
FROM tbl_allTransactions
WHERE tbl_allTransactions.transType in ('Expense', 'Budget') AND tbl_allTransactions.transMonth = @transMonth
GROUP BY tbl_allTransactions.transMonth) as SumOftransAmount2
FROM tbl_allTransactions
WHERE tbl_allTransactions.userID=@userID
```

Comment: Hi @Aishwar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.